# How to use var - variable outside of try-catch block

Tags: c#, linq, var

I have a `var` result in `try/catch`. I want to use the result out of the `try/catch` block, but I can not declare before the `try` block because the `var` gets the type at runtime. Can I do it?

```
public long getConfigVal<T>( int key, ref T sResult)
  {
        var myValue;
        try
        {                    
            myValue = (from el in keyValueList 
       select (string)el.Attribute("value").Value).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    if (sResult is string)
                        sResult = (T)(object)myValue;
                    if (sResult is int)
                        sResult = (T)(object)int.Parse(myValue);
                    if (sResult is DateTime)
                        sResult = (T)(object)DateTime.Parse(myValue); 
}
```

Or is there any way to use `myValue` outside of the block?

Comment: You mean `el.Value` is of anonymous type?

Comment: It can be: int , string or dateTime

Comment: How's that? Is it `dynamic` maybe? `object`? There is no such type as "either int, string or DateTime".

Comment: worksss, Evk!! , Maybe you want to answer so I will accept this answer?

Comment: Isn't `myValue` **always** a `string`? It has to be or else you couldn't pass it to the Parse methods. `T` might change, but `myValue`'s compile time type won't

Comment: You should not use generics when the caller is only ever allowed to provide one of a few fixed types.   The whole idea of generics is that the method should work *regardless* of what type is provided.  If you want to have a method that can handle a small fixed list of types, have different overloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Evk for the good answer (But in the comments...)
I declare myValue as an object:

```
 string myValue;
try
{                    
    myValue = from el in keyValueList select el.Value;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: Actually that was not an answer, I was just trying to figure out what is the type of `el.Value`...

Comment: If you don’t like strongly typed values ( like one rovided by “bar”) consider switching to other language like JavaScript. Changing “var” to “object” is not a good recommendation, please don’t do it.

Comment: Changing “var” to “object” is not a good recommendation- why?

Comment: @user1012506 because using object is the old way of generics. There are (type-)saver ways nowadays.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot declare a variable having the receiver type be `var` and then decide not to initialize it inline.

Assuming `select el.Value` doesn't return an anonymous type you'll need to resort to using an explicitly typed variable.

i.e.

```
IEnumerable<int> myValue;
```

for example:

Comment: It is just for int, no?

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with the `try/catch`, you must initialise usages of `var` where you define them. They *infer* the type from the right hand part of the assignment - they are still typed. `var myInt = 1;` is still typed to an integer, you just let the compiler infer that from the literal `1`. What you are trying to do can't be done in C# with implicit typing.

'...because the var gets the type at runtime.' - nope, it's all at compile time. You just need to declare the type of your variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don’t need to declare a var myValue.

You have a generic method, so you need T as resultType. Why you don’t use this?

It’s easier or at least saver to cast to a generic type, than declare a var as dynamic type.

And this answer might not contain code, but looking for an Extension Method for casting string to a value-Type..., or string isn’t that big effort to get a save solution.
;-)

Answer (score -4):

you can also use a dynamic variable:

```
dynamic _myvalue;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        try
        {
          var myValue =
                from el in keyValueList
                select el.Value;
            _myvalue = myValue;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a far worse option, `dynamic` and `var` are **very** different things.

Comment: Since a var needs a datatype at runtime, dynamic will be the most efficient way to mimic the var's datatype

Comment: There is no computing type at run time in the code shown in the post. Replacing “car” with “dynamic” is as bad recommendation as using “object”.

Comment: @DaanV `var` is a **fixed** type, that doesn't exists at runtime, it's the same as declaring a variable of the proper type without naming it explictly, and it's still type safe. The only practical effect is obscuring the real type from the developer. `dynamic` on the other hand makes everything to be computed at runtime, so you lose type safety and makes everything slower. You even lose intellisense when using it.